# Symfony|Twig: update data after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

Index.html.twig

```
{% if amount.low != 0 %}
    <p class="amount">{{ amount.low|round(0, 'floor') }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Filter1").change(function() {
        var input = $(this).val();

        if(inputCPU.length >= 1) {
            var data = {input: input};
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ROOT_URL + "default/update/data",
                dataType: 'json',
                timeout: 3000,
                success: function(response){
                    $(".amount").html(response.result); ???
                        console.log(response.result);

                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Error with showing the filter.') //debug reasons
                }
            })
        }
    });
})
```

Controller:

```
public function updateDataAction(Request $request)
{


    $amount = //db call

    return ??
}
```

I'm a bit stuck on this code. I've a page where I show some data (amount), above there is a filter where users can manipulate the amount. How can I change the amount.low with the new filtered data when a filter is used? I'm stuck on what I should return in my controller and what the success whould be in my javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#creating-a-json-response

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

// ...

public function updateDataAction(Request $request)
{


    $amount = //db call

    return new JsonResponse(array('amount' => $amount));

}
```

Comment: For some reason I'm not geting any results back? It's like I'm not going into the updateDataAction methode. You have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: You could try to request that route/action straight from the browser.